# pdflatex gets stuck while processing draft images

Tags: linux

I have a document I've been writing using TeXSudio + Texlive on windows. I can build everything in windows just fine but when I go to linux, compilation hangs at a certain point.

The last line before compilation hangs is:

```
[6] [7 <./Figures/SM.png>] [8 <./Figures/memory.png>] [9 <./Figures/asyncOps.png>]
```

At which point it will just stop doing anything until interrupted.
The command I am using is:

```
latexmk main -pdf
```

TeXstudio is using the command:

```
pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --shell-escape "main".tex
```

which I tried (minus the synctex), but the result was the same.

Is there something else TeXstudio is doing under the hood that I need to do in CLI? This has happened on a machine with a modern i7 and 16 GB of ram so I don't think it is a resource issue.

Comment: and what is the code on page 10?

Comment: somewhere just before it hangs eg on page 8 add `\tracingall` so then you will see what it is doing. Do not use `--shell-escape` on any document unless you are _very_ sure you know what it is doing.

Comment: where would the trace output go?

Comment: Looking at output with tracing I noticed that the C-code that got spit out when I hit control+C was referring to a specific figure which had an underscore in the name. In TeXStudio I was able to reference that filename with an underscore but linux must've parsed it differently and gotten stuck in some low level code. Looks to be resolved, will see if it works on the target platform.

Comment: tracingall is showing tex not C execution and should be operating system indpendent file parsing. However if you got it working I suggest this is closed as non-reproducible?

Comment: Have you tried TeXstudio on Linux? Are the versions of pdflatex installed different? (`pdlfatex[.exe] -v`)

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that one of my image names had an underscore. In Windows TexStudio, the include graphics to the file in latex thus included '\_'.

These characters seem to have been parsed differently at some point in linux, as when I renamed the image and got rid of the \_ in latex, it compiled fine.

I discovered this because when I would hit control-C after compilation hang, the error that got spit out was from an internal C function which showed the offending image include string it got stuck on as an argument.